# SQL Server 2008 R2 Drops Connections when Anti-Virus Scan is running

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise (SP2) cluster (2 nodes Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, NetApp Shared storage).

There are 5 instances all running on this cluster in an active passive configuration and we have found that occasionally during the time that the weekly antivirus scan runs, one of the instances starts to drop connections and becomes inaccessible for about an hour (the scan runs for 2 hours), all the other instances are fine.

In the error log, we see the following messages when the server is inaccessible:

> TCP connection closed but a child process of SQL Server may be holding
>   a duplicate of the connection's socket.  Consider enabling the
>   TcpAbortiveClose SQL Server registry setting and restarting SQL
>   Server. If the problem persists contact Technical Support.
>
> Error: 26073 Severity: 16 State: 1.

They are also accompanied by the following error (although not all the time):

> Process 0:0:0 (0x15540) Worker 0x0000000E721041A0 appears to be
>   non-yielding on Scheduler 20. Thread creation time: 13025544955370.
>   Approx Thread CPU Used: kernel 0 ms user 0 ms. Process Utilization
>   0%. System Idle 91%. Interval: 119402 ms.

During this time there are also some warnings with IO operations taking longer than 15 seconds to complete.

What I'd like to know is:

We have excluded all the locations recommended by Microsoft from scanning, so why is this only happening during the scan, can these issues just be caused by the extra load of the scan, they're pretty powerful boxes so I wouldn't have thought that the extra load would cause a problem, and the time at which this runs, the server is not busy, also if it is caused by the scan why does the problem only stay for 1 hour rather than the full 2?

What is the TcpAbortiveClose registry setting and what are the implications of this setting, I know how to set it from the Microsoft KB article(http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2491214), but I can't find any documentation on this setting anywhere on what it does or whether it is a good idea.

Comment: Like @AaronBertrand said ... stop using AntiVirus. Terrible practice.

Comment: We're an antivirus vendor, we make the AV software and so are made to use it via company policy, not a lot I can do about that I'm afraid.

Comment: You may want to raise this with the development staff (I assume you're using your company's own product), because it's probably causing clients a headache, too.

Comment: @steoleary if antivirus is necessary on your sql server (which is not a good practice - as many have pointed out), atleast have an **exclusion** in the scanning of `.mdf, .ldf, .bak, .ndf` and `sql server binaries`.

Comment: I would absolutely suggest running antivirus on your SQL Servers; however, definitely exclude the extensions for all your data, transaction log, error log, and backup files (.log, .txt, .mdf, .ndf, .ldf, .bak, .bkp, .trn, .hbc for Hyperbac, whatever else you use, etc.).  I would keep scanning executables of all types, including SQL Server binaries - the scan on starting up is insignificant, and once they're running, AV scans of the binaries are largely irrelevant.  Keep the AV away from the big, non-executable data files.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are still running SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1, so I would suggest that you update your software.  If you update to SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 CU 2 there is a fix for this problem.

You can read about this particular problem at: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2491214

I would recommend not applying the "workaround" but just getting up-to-date with SP2 CU2 (at least).  You should know that SP2 CU8 is available.

Comment: We are using SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 (10.50.4000) that article suggests that CU2 for SQL 2008 SP2 contains the fix for this issue and CU6 for SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM, so according to the article we shouldn't be seeing this issue with the patch levels we are on.

Comment: @steoleary I think you are mixed up about R2, SP2 and CU2. 2008 R2 SP2 RTM is 10.50.4000. If you had CU2 installed, [your build # would be 10.50.4263](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2740411). At 4000 you could still be seeing this issue because it wasn't fixed until 4263 was published. Install that ([or better](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2871401)). Or just stop using Anti-Virus junk against your SQL Server.

Comment: Hi Aaron, I'm not mixed up about the versions, just the article says that it's CU2 for SQL Server 2008 SP2 that fixes it, not CU2 for SQL 2008 R2 SP2.  Direct from the article: "Cumulative update package 6 for SQL Server 2008 R2
The fix for this issue was first released in Cumulative Update 6." and then again a bit later for SQL Server 2008 : "Cumulative update package 2 for SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 2 The fix for this issue was first released in Cumulative Update 2 for SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 2."

Comment: @steoleary It looks like I misread the KB. Apologies.  I note that the article also mentions that the problem is related to SQL Server Native Client 10.0.

Comment: No worries, I have checked the native clients used by all machines connecting to this instance and they are all either the patched version or v11, looks like I'll be raising a call with Microsoft tomorrow morning :-(

Comment: Hi Steoleary, did you ever get to the bottom of this? We have 2 boxes that report this error intermittently - Non-yielding IOCP Listener. Whereby SQL Locks up for 20 mins or so. Problem is that we're running 2008R2 - SP3 (10.50.6000) so the Non-yielding Scheduler article doesn't help much!

Comment: @mhsqldba what is your max dop setting ? Default of 0 means use all threads. You should change it away from default.

Comment: Thanks Kin, MaxDop is 12 which seems to work well in our environment. Just to update my comment above - we did resolve it. I pinned it down to AV scan. AV had the correct exclusions (mdf, ndf, ldf, etc.) However, the guy who DBA'd here before me was "not necessarily a good fit for the job" - he'd misnamed one of the files with a .ndt extension (note the T - not easy to spot immediately among 40 or so files!). Therefore AV was free to lock the file up and work its evil! Thanks anyway.